# I am reviving a slightly dated Webscraper, I am getting a invalid syntax error

Tags: python, web-scraping

A few months ago with the help of many beautiful souls on stackoverflow I learned a good amount. However my brain retention is small. I am getting a syntax error trying to run my script. I am sure it is something very basic I am missing, any help would be great. Code and error posted.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint

# sleep(randint(10,20))


realtor_data = []

for page in range(1, 34):
    print(f"Scraping page {page}...")
    url = f"https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/hoover_al/pg-{page}"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

    for agent_card in soup.select("div.agent-list-card-title.mobile-only"):
        name = agent_card.find("div", {"class": "agent-name"})
        number = agent_card.find("div", {"class": "agent-phone"})
        realtor_data.append(
            [
                name.getText().strip(),
                number.getText().strip() if number is not None else "N/A"                
            ],
        )

with open("data.csv", "w") as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    w.writerow(["NAME:", "PHONE NUMBER:", "CITY:"])
    w.writerows(realtor_data)

import pandas as pd
a=pd.read_csv("data.csv" , encoding='latin-1')
a2 = a.iloc[:,[0,1]]
a3 = a.iloc[:,[2]]
a3 = a3.fillna("Hoover")
b=pd.concat([a2,a3],axis=1)
b.to_csv("data.csv")
```

---

```
Syntax Error: Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python hoover.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python hoover.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Sorry if the formatting is poor.

Comment: How exactly are you invoking the script?

Comment: `python hoover.py` is something you'd type at your operating system's shell prompt.  It's not something meaningful inside of Python.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Sorry I am clearly beginner, I wrote the script in sublime and I am trying to execute it through anaconda prompt. I am not quite sure how to actually run the script. My process was opening anaconda prompt, typing "python" then "python hoover.py" to run the script. I guess I am not sure how to actually run the script then. I sound so dumb haha but thank you guys for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that '>>>' before your command? The problem is that you are trying to call python to execute your file within the python shell.

Try running your command in the terminal, without calling 'python' to execute first.

Comment: Thank you and thank you all so much! You were completely right. I went to the file path and opened command prompt ran the script and it worked perfectly. Thank you for helping the newbie.